# after install wp spinner plugin my website show me error

Tags: wordpress

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare true_plugins_activate() (previously declared in /home/u120924469/domains/verityproduct.com/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:7871) in /home/u120924469/domains/verityproduct.com/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 7902

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace the functions.php file in wp-includes with the original wordpress file. Don't forget to backup the old file before you replace it.

Comment: thanks for answer where can i find original Wordpress file please

Comment: Here - find the file and replace it with your FTP. https://wordpress.org/latest.zip @sanjeevrana02

Comment: @sanjeevrana02 you are welcome, let me know if it helped or not. Otherwise we will need to take a look deeper into your problem.

Comment: Notice: require(): read of 5863 bytes failed with errno=12 Cannot allocate memory in /home/u120924469/domains/verityproduct.com/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 230

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/u120924469/domains/verityproduct.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-http-proxy.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in /home/u120924469/domains/verityproduct.com/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 230

Comment: Notice: is_embed was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) in /home/u120924469/domains/verityproduct.com/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5313

Comment: Notice: is_search was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) in /home/u120924469/domains/verityproduct.com/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5313

Comment: Hmmmm well could you restore the previous file back please? It looks like a plugin conflict then.

Comment: The main reason why is this happening to you is that you may use other plugin from the same author which is using the same function name as the spinner and you can not redeclare 2 same functions in wordpress with the same name. Each function needs to have a different name to make it work otherwise you will receive error.